# How to Modify CiviCRM settings file

Tags: settings, files

How can I modify the CiviCRM settings file so that the CiviCRM extension directory is set using settings files variables. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $civicrm_setting variable to over-ride your CiviCRM settings. You can find documentation [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/customize/settings/).

To set extension directory you can use below snippet

```
global $civicrm_setting;
$civicrm_setting['Directory Preferences']['extensionsDir'] = '/var/www/html/trcbtp/drupal/sites/default/civicrm_extensions';
```

You can also use civicrm token variable for dynamic path

```
1. [cms.root]
2. [civicrm.root]
3. [civicrm.files]
```

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Can I run that command on the command line of my web server? Thanks

Comment: What command? Do you mean the command to append the line in civicrm.settings.php?

Comment: Yup Pradeep. Sorry coz I am new to this one. That's why. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, You can use commands to append the line.

Comment: Hi Pradeep, do you know a a sample of video tutorial for this one? So that I can see the step-by-step procedure? Thanks so much!